# Server going offline randomly - Problem with MySQL various alerts in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin

Webapp goes offline randomly, the offline time is less than 2minutes. (Because the downtime checker intervals are set for 2 min test and it isn't reporting this). But users are complaining about unavailability.

Getting various alerts in phpMyadmin doubts this is something related to a MySQL connection drop.

Here are the alerts that are displayed in phpmyadmin:
[image: Alerts from phpMyadmin]

Configuration.

- ubuntu 16.04LTS up to date
- CloudFlare enabled
- PHP version: 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- Apache
- MYSQL Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Looking these values it seems your tables aren't indexed (properly). Without knowing enough about your application my best bet would be:

- Restart MySQL server (this is a must)
- Monitor these values after restart
- Enable and examine slow query logs, thus identifying queries causing these issues
- Run `EXPLAIN` on these queries and try to introduce proper indices

Comment: @VarunHaridas if you can add more details I can give you a more detailed answer

Comment: Sure i can provide that, can you give me a brief outline of what other data you need to analyse this scenario.

Comment: For a start, some anonymized slow queries will do it.